# RxJava - How to zip 2 completables and return an observable?

Tags: rx-java

Let's say I have 2 Completables, Completable1 and Completable2.
What I want to do is to return just("result") after both of them complete.

If these were Observables, I could use something like
Observable.zip(Ob1, Ob2).map(() -> just("result")) but how can I do it for completables?

I am trying something like 
Completable1.andThen(Completable2).map(() -> just("result")

but this doesn't work because you can't map completables after they are completed. (Not sure if andThen is the correct one to use instead of zip().
Can anyone suggested a correct answer?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
Completable.complete()
  .andThen(Completable.complete())
  .andThen(Observable.just("result"))
```